# not found(deploying via digitalocean, nginx, ubuntu, Gunicorn )

Tags: django, nginx, web-deployment, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I tried to deploy Django via digitalocean, nginx, ubuntu, and Gunicorn.

I followed the tutorial [that digitaloccean provided](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04).
Everything was fine before the step of binding it with Gunicorn.

I was able to use the run "`manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`"and was able to see the website on port 8000 of the IP address;

however when I tried to run `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 biostar.wsgi`

```
(virtualcrew) corey@crew:~/digitalocceancrew/digitalcrew$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 biostar.wsgi
[2021-06-23 12:55:36 +0000] [134047] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-06-23 12:55:36 +0000] [134047] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (134047)
[2021-06-23 12:55:36 +0000] [134047] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-06-23 12:55:36 +0000] [134049] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 134049
```

,and tried to connect to the IP address again, the 404 not found error occurred.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHwKv.png)

But when I tried to run `sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 biostar.wsgi`

```
(virtualcrew) corey@crew:~/digitalocceancrew/digitalcrew$ sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 biostar.wsgi
[2021-06-23 12:54:09 +0000] [134021] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-06-23 12:54:09 +0000] [134021] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (134021)
[2021-06-23 12:54:09 +0000] [134021] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-06-23 12:54:09 +0000] [134023] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 134023
celery error No module named 'django'
[2021-06-23 12:54:09 +0000] [134023] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 383, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/corey/digitalocceancrew/digitalcrew/biostar/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[2021-06-23 12:54:09 +0000] [134023] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 134023)
[2021-06-23 12:54:09 +0000] [134021] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-06-23 12:54:09 +0000] [134021] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I also tried every port of the IP address but none of them worked.

This is the output of `systemctl status gunicorn.service`

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-06-19 09:14:20 UTC; 4 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 34545 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 1136)
     Memory: 111.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
             ├─34545 /home/corey/digitalocceancrew/virtualcrew/bin/python /home/corey/digitalocceancrew/virtualcrew/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock biostar.wsgi:application
             ├─34557 /home/corey/digitalocceancrew/virtualcrew/bin/python /home/corey/digitalocceancrew/virtualcrew/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock biostar.wsgi:application
             ├─34558 /home/corey/digitalocceancrew/virtualcrew/bin/python /home/corey/digitalocceancrew/virtualcrew/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock biostar.wsgi:application
             └─34559 /home/corey/digitalocceancrew/virtualcrew/bin/python /home/corey/digitalocceancrew/virtualcrew/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock biostar.wsgi:application

Jun 23 11:59:20 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-23 07:59:20,623        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /.env
Jun 23 11:59:20 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [23/Jun/2021:07:59:20 -0400] "GET /.env HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "python-requests/2.25.1"
Jun 23 12:06:31 crew gunicorn[34558]: WARNING        2021-06-23 08:06:31,852        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 23 12:06:31 crew gunicorn[34558]:  - - [23/Jun/2021:08:06:31 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
Jun 23 12:24:40 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-23 08:24:40,352        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /.env
Jun 23 12:24:40 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [23/Jun/2021:08:24:40 -0400] "GET /.env HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jun 23 12:24:40 crew gunicorn[34558]: WARNING        2021-06-23 08:24:40,553        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 23 12:24:40 crew gunicorn[34558]:  - - [23/Jun/2021:08:24:40 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jun 23 12:24:54 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-23 08:24:54,081        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 23 12:24:54 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [23/Jun/2021:08:24:54 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

And this is the output of `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn`

```
(virtualcrew) corey@crew:~/digitalocceancrew/digitalcrew$ sudo journalctl -u gunicorn
-- Logs begin at Sun 2021-06-20 07:46:26 UTC, end at Wed 2021-06-23 12:51:37 UTC. --
Jun 20 07:46:26 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 03:46:26,682        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1wZGZfMjEudHh0.xml
Jun 20 07:46:26 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:03:46:26 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1wZGZfMjEudHh0.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 07:46:51 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-20 03:46:51,386        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS0xMDUtcGRmLnR4dA==.xml
Jun 20 07:46:51 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:03:46:51 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS0xMDUtcGRmLnR4dA==.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 09:04:48 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 05:04:48,093        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /.env
Jun 20 09:04:48 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:05:04:48 -0400] "GET /.env HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jun 20 09:04:48 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-20 05:04:48,585        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 20 09:04:48 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:05:04:48 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jun 20 09:24:00 crew gunicorn[34558]: WARNING        2021-06-20 05:24:00,154        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /_ignition/execute-solution
Jun 20 09:24:00 crew gunicorn[34558]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:05:24:00 -0400] "GET /_ignition/execute-solution HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "python-requests/2.18.4"
Jun 20 09:47:12 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-20 05:47:12,781        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 20 09:47:12 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:05:47:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "-"
Jun 20 09:47:13 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 05:47:13,166        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 20 09:47:13 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:05:47:13 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)"
Jun 20 09:58:11 crew gunicorn[34558]: WARNING        2021-06-20 05:58:11,030        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /.env
Jun 20 09:58:11 crew gunicorn[34558]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:05:58:11 -0400] "GET /.env HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jun 20 09:58:11 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-20 05:58:11,217        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 20 09:58:11 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:05:58:11 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jun 20 10:11:55 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 06:11:55,505        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 20 10:11:55 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:06:11:55 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/>
Jun 20 10:40:41 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-20 06:40:41,937        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /.env
Jun 20 10:40:41 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:06:40:41 -0400] "GET /.env HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jun 20 10:40:42 crew gunicorn[34558]: WARNING        2021-06-20 06:40:42,935        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 20 10:40:42 crew gunicorn[34558]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:06:40:42 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jun 20 11:38:28 crew gunicorn[34558]: WARNING        2021-06-20 07:38:28,734        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS0zOC1wZGYudHh0.xml
Jun 20 11:38:28 crew gunicorn[34558]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:07:38:28 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS0zOC1wZGYudHh0.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 11:43:16 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 07:43:16,900        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /robots.txt
Jun 20 11:43:16 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:07:43:16 -0400] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
Jun 20 11:43:17 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-20 07:43:17,763        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 20 11:43:17 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:07:43:17 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
Jun 20 11:46:49 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 07:46:49,299        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS0zODFhbWNvOWkudHh0.xml
Jun 20 11:46:49 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:07:46:49 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS0zODFhbWNvOWkudHh0.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 11:47:02 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-20 07:47:02,987        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS03Zmh0c2VsODUudHh0.xml
Jun 20 11:47:02 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:07:47:02 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS03Zmh0c2VsODUudHh0.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 11:52:56 crew gunicorn[34558]: WARNING        2021-06-20 07:52:56,575        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS16c3FiMG12ZmMudHh0.xml
Jun 20 11:52:56 crew gunicorn[34558]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:07:52:56 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS16c3FiMG12ZmMudHh0.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 11:53:48 crew gunicorn[34558]: WARNING        2021-06-20 07:53:48,748        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1wZGZfMTM5LnR4dA==.xml
Jun 20 11:53:48 crew gunicorn[34558]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:07:53:48 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1wZGZfMTM5LnR4dA==.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 11:56:02 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 07:56:02,167        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
Jun 20 11:56:02 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:07:56:02 -0400] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "http://128.199.92.91:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Geck>
Jun 20 12:04:31 crew gunicorn[34558]: WARNING        2021-06-20 08:04:31,453        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1wZGZfMTM4LnR4dA==.xml
Jun 20 12:04:31 crew gunicorn[34558]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:08:04:31 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1wZGZfMTM4LnR4dA==.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 12:05:44 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-20 08:05:44,775        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /mathematical_ideas_12th_edition_online_free.pdf
Jun 20 12:05:44 crew gunicorn[34557]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:08:05:44 -0400] "GET /mathematical_ideas_12th_edition_online_free.pdf HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKi>
Jun 20 12:13:36 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 08:13:36,178        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1kcXQ2Mm52YXMudHh0.xml
Jun 20 12:13:36 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:08:13:36 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1kcXQ2Mm52YXMudHh0.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 12:15:09 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 08:15:09,785        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1wZGZfMTc3LnR4dA==.xml
Jun 20 12:15:09 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:08:15:09 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1wZGZfMTc3LnR4dA==.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 12:17:00 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 08:17:00,000        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
Jun 20 12:17:00 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:08:16:59 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"
Jun 20 12:22:12 crew gunicorn[34559]: WARNING        2021-06-20 08:22:12,841        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1jcnUweW5kdjEudHh0.xml
Jun 20 12:22:12 crew gunicorn[34559]:  - - [20/Jun/2021:08:22:12 -0400] "GET /MTI4LjE5OS45Mi45MS1jcnUweW5kdjEudHh0.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
Jun 20 12:27:35 crew gunicorn[34557]: WARNING        2021-06-20 08:27:35,621        log.log_response        224        Not Found: /
```

This is the output of `ls -l /run/gunicorn.sock` and `netstat -tlpn | grep 'gunicorn'`(The second one does not have any output)

```
(virtualcrew) corey@crew:~/digitalocceancrew/digitalcrew$ sudo ls -l /run/gunicorn.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jun 19 09:03 /run/gunicorn.sock
(virtualcrew) corey@crew:~/digitalocceancrew/digitalcrew$ sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 'gunicorn'
(virtualcrew) corey@crew:~/digitalocceancrew/digitalcrew$
```

When I type in `sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`, it started running and stuck.(no output)

```
(virtualcrew) corey@crew:~/digitalocceancrew/digitalcrew$ sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Output of `sudo netstat -tulpn`

```
(virtualcrew) corey@crew:~/digitalocceancrew/digitalcrew$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      90046/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      559/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1163/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4284/postgres       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      90046/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1163/sshd: /usr/sbi 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           559/systemd-resolve
```

I have the following questions:

1. What might possibly cause this error?
2. Does being able to run it on local server means that the error is not caused by the source code?
3. What can I try to fix this issue?

Thank you !!!

Comment: links to pictures of text is annoying, and prevents me from telling you which module you need to install since I can't copy-and-paste the name here...

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I have copied it again.

Comment: The Python process that is running cannot find django (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`), which is why gunicorn (and celery) fails to start.